# Am I using the subtract tool wrong in Sketchup?

Tags: 3d, drawing, modeling, sketchup, paint-3d

[image][image]It's my first attempt to making a staircase with a 3' curved knee wall as a railing. I am trying to remove a portion of the curved wall along a staircase to do this. I tried to use the solid tools subtract tool but nothing happens when I try to subtract the highlighted portion. Going to keep trying, and see if maybe the wall I am trying to remove isn't a solid?